# How can I send application health data to nagios from a spring application?

Tags: java, spring, monitoring, nagios

I would like to send the following health information to Nagios for monitoring:

1. Various connection pool statistics and connections statuses
2. RabbitMQ connection status
3. Business logic metrics like, "Number of transactions processed"

I am aware of the spring-actuator project and that works great for active monitoring. However, this app resides on premise inside the firewall of our customers so we can't use Nagios to actively monitor this application.

Are there any frameworks that work nicely with spring to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still benefit from the Actuator project. I would solve it by writing a scheduled method, which reads the monitoring data from the Actuator endpoints and sends it to Nagios. If Nagios has a REST API for that, you can just use the RestTemplate from Spring.